# Density function implied by a stochastic differential equation

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Imagine we have an Ito process of the functional form:
$$
dX_t = \mu(t,X_t)\,dt + \sigma(t,X_t)\,dW_t
$$

where $W$ is a Brownian motion, $0 < t < T$ and $\int_0^T\sigma(t, X_t)\,dW_t$ is square-integrable

I am hoping this question is not too elementary, but what is the strategy to plot the density function of $X$ implied by the equation above?

Comment: Not really elementary at all! The density you are after can be given by the solution of Fokker-Planck PDE associated with this diffusion, but actually solving this is rarely easy and you will usually be looking at numerical methods. If you want a quick plot one option is to just discretise the SDE and then simulate the process.